# Using unapply as constructor in match

Tags: scala

Is it good style in Scala to "abuse" the unapply method for pattern matching? What I wanted to do, is matching an object against another, and constructing the other object. Since I am fairly new in Scala, I wound up with the following solution. But it doesnt seem really right to use the unapply methode like this, since it is intended as an extractor. Could someone please give me feedback on this?

```
 object Poker {
    def unapply(hand: Hand): Option[Poker] = if(hand.countValueGroups().exists(_._2 == 4)) Some(new Poker(hand)) else None
  }

 val h = Hand("AC As AH Ad 2h")

 h match {
   case Poker(han) => println("POKER!!!"+han)
   case _ => println("?????")
 }
```

Comment: If it is bad practice, then I'm pretty screwed ;) Although, in scala 2.11 you could be more efficient with a [name based extractor](http://hseeberger.github.io/blog/2013/10/04/name-based-extractors-in-scala-2-dot-11/)

Comment: What use other than pattern matching does `unapply` even have?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll look into the name based extractor.

Comment: The reason I asked, was because the tutorial made it seem like the main purpose of extracors was to return the state of a given object. But then again the Scala tutorial isnt the the best I have seen :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this should be bad practice, so I'd say the answer is *no*, this is normal practice. As one commenter said, the mere purpose of `unapply` is to be used in pattern matching. While pattern matching is mostly used with the companion object of a `case class`, the concept is deliberately open to other extractors (example: regular expressions).

The only thing that's weird in your example is to return `Option[Poker]` with `Poker` begin a singleton object. Since you can't do much with that, probably you want to use a `Boolean` instead:

```
object Poker {
  def unapply(hand: Hand): Boolean = 
   hand.countValueGroups().exists(_._2 == 4)
}

case class Hand(s: String) {
  def countValueGroups(): List[(Any, Int)] = List("foo" -> 4) // ???
}

val h = Hand("AC As AH Ad 2h")

h match {
  case Poker() => println("POKER!!!")
  case _ => println("?????")
}
```

Comment: Actually there is a companion class, which I just left out for brevity. You can look at the full code here: http://www.codesend.com/view/b34cbe93acc51f1fd5558dd42af58ba7/